# get php file from folder using html <a href="">

Tags: php, html

My site is http:\www.xxx.com/xxx
I'm having problem to get the specific file inside a folder

The file is inside admin_pages folder under the root
The menus folder are under root too
In my   i put

```
<a href="../admin_pages/adminAtividadesByMonthChart.php">
```

and it returns to http:\www.xxx.com

If i use

```
<a href="../../admin_pages/adminAtividadesByMonthChart.php">
```

Its the same...

This is my image project

[image]

any help?

Comment: Use php `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, it will give you root path

Comment: U have use  like 
<a href="admin_pages/adminAtividadesByMonthChart.php">

Comment: <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>admin_pages/adminAtividadesByMonthChart.php">
Try this

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path?

Comment: With this i have HTTP 500, due to the file requires include folder, in my php i have require_once("../include/membersite_config.php"); and i have this error: Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './include/fg_membersite.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/php') in /home/ebspma/public_html/gesdocente/include/membersite_config.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

You may use a constant for base url.

It may be BASE_URL

So ;

```
<?php
define('BASE_URL', 'http://www.example.com');
<a href="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>/admin_pages/adminAtividadesByMonthChart.php">
```

Good luck